# Creating streams to a hidden service

Tags: onion-services

Looking for help understanding the following line from the rend-spec:

```
 754    To open TCP connections to Bob's location-hidden service, Alice's OP sends
 755    a RELAY_COMMAND_BEGIN cell along the established circuit, using the special
 756    address "", and a chosen port.
```

what is the special address and the port ? Is "" actually the special address, and I asume the port is the Hsdir port for bob or the rp ?

Answer (score 1):

I guess this special address is the .onion address, which is the hash of public key of Bob.

Answer (score 0):

<guesses>
I think that the address may be "" because you've already got a circuit to the hidden service's server.
Therefore the address "" is taken to mean the local server.

I think the port is the port of the hidden service you're trying to connect to (probably 80).

</guesses>